# Switching views in UINavigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Hi i am new in iphone programing...My requirement is to go to from menu page in my app to 2nd view on click of button which is a table view then from there to other views...lets say an screen showing image, from this screen i want to come back to main menu..

so is it possible to do it using UINavigationController...as far i know...Navigation control allows switching using stack....so you can come back to previous screen only

Please help me!!!

or should i do it without using navigation controller...doing all stuff keeping a view controller as a switch manager and then from it managing all the screens..????????

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you want but here a few idea's.

If you just want to add a screen (no stack), use `addSubview:`

If you want a overlay witch you can dismiss, use `presentModalViewController:animated:`

Want to use a stack and a button to go directly to the root, use

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you want to use UINavigationController to manage the views/viewcontrollers.

to push a new viewcontroller use:

```
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

to pop back to the first viewcontroller use:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

to pop back to a specific viewcontroller use:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use navigation controller then u declare a variable of navigation controller in app-delegate  file as like 
in app deleagte.h

> UINavigationController *navigationController;
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

and in appdelegate.m file

> @synthesize navigationController;
>   - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
>       // Override point for customization after application launch
>       [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
>       [window makeKeyAndVisible];
>   }

and when u call next views then use this code on action of button or cell of table view

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];

above line for push view.

Comment: and if u want to pop then see below answer.